# Problem with Code-First Database and PostgreSql

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, code-first, npgsql

I am using Code-First project and my database is PostgreSql. When I migrated my project to PostgreSql by using Npgsql v.2.2.7 everything worked fine. I need to use the new version of Npsql. To achieve my goal I upgraded Npsql to the latest version (4.1.5). Now when I use add-migration I get the following error :

> *The Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework' registered in the application config file for
> the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' could not be loaded.
> Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the
> assembly is available to the running application. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.*

I have read many articles about the issue but none of them assisted me in solving my problem. Also, I used Dapper Contrib in my project. The problem occurred after upgrading Npgsql as I mentioned above.

What is the correct way to use this package?

here is my App.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <entityFramework>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
          <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
          <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="KMSystemContext" connectionString="Server=****;Database=KMSystem;User Id=postgres;Password=***;" providerName="Npgsql" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Installed packages are :

- Npgsql 4.1.5
- EntityFramework 6.0.0.0

Comment: It would be helpful if you also posted the config file sections that are relevant based on the article linked in your question.

Comment: @EdSF Thanks for your response I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of searching we installed *EntityFramework6.Npgsql 6.4.1* package in all solution's projects (There are some class liberaries and WinApps projects in the solution). With the update of this package, *Npgsql* update to the new version *(4.1.3)* too. So the app.config change to :

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
```

It needs to be changed app.config as below. Just in the project that DataContext has located (DataLayer)

```
<provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
```

Replace with :

```
<provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
```

at the end, we have to set DataLayer (With DataContext) as StartUp Project.
(Set as StartUp Project) and then we can migrate code first project with *PostgreSql* database by using *add-migration* and *update-database* commands in *PackageManagerConsole*.